# Reference Request: topological h-cobordism theorem in higher dimensions

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

The [h-cobordism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-cobordism) is true in the topological and in the smooth category in dimensions $\ge 6$. (By "dimension, I mean the dimension of the ambient cobordism instead of the dimension of the boundary, as it is in this wikipedia-link)

The smooth case of dimension  $\ge 6$ was first proven by Smale around 1962 (e.g. S. Smale, "On the structure of manifolds" Amer. J. Math., 84 (1962) pp. 387–399), but who did the topological case of dimension $\ge 6$ first and can you give me a reference?

Answer (score 1):

E. H. Connell, in [this](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1256054669) 1967 paper.